# TypeError: response.type is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to refactor some code because of an updated dependencies, a function now return a promise. So I am trying to use async await.

Here is the original code

```
handler: (req, h) => {
            const response = h.response(Prometheus.register.metrics());
            response.type(Prometheus.register.contentType);
            return response;
        },
```

Here is my refactor code

```
handler: async () => {
            try {
                const response = await Prometheus.register
                    .metrics()
                    .catch((err) => {
                        throw err;
                    });
                response.type(Prometheus.register.contentType);
                return response;
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            return null;
        },
```

I am getting a `TypeError: response.type is not a function`. Any help is appreciated, as I have google and looked through other questions on here but I still quite don't understand it.

Comment: Did you mean `response.type = Prometheus.register.contentType;`?

Comment: No it didn't work because it's a string. Got the error TypeError: Cannot create property 'type' on string

Comment: If `response` is a string, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Don't use `catch` if you already use `await`